# Why is there repetition in counting the number of cases in this probability question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

The question is as follows:

> There are 6 passengers on a subway car getting off each getting off the car at one of 7 stops. What is the probability that
>
> **a.)** 2 of the passengers get off at the same one stop and the other 4 passengers get off at another same stop.
>
> **b.)** 2 passengers get off at one stop, 2 other passengers get off at another same stop and the other 2 passengers get off at a third same stop.

So, the event space is the $\{1,2,\cdots, 7\}^6$, where the $i$th component of the vector is the stop that the $i$th passenger gets off at. There are $7^6$ such tuples.

In the a.), we choose $1$ stop and $2$ of the  $6$ passengers (these are the first two passengers that get off at the first stop, there are ${7\choose 1}{6\choose 2}$ possibilities), and then we choose $1$ stop of the remaining $6$ possible stops (and $4$ of the remaining $4$ passengers). So the probability is
$$
\frac{\displaystyle {7\choose 1}{6\choose 2}{6\choose 1}{4\choose 4}}{7^6}
$$
In b.), we can attempt the same thing, choosing $2$ of $6$ passengers for $1$ of $7$ stops, then $2$ of the remaining $4$ passengers for $1$ of the remaining $6$ stops, then another $2$ of the remaining $2$ passengers for $1$ of the remaining $5$ stops, and so *in theory* we should arrive at
$$
\frac{\displaystyle{7\choose 1} {6\choose 2} {6\choose 1} {4\choose 2} {5\choose 1} {2\choose 2}}{y^6}
$$
but according to the solution given this is actually *wrong*, and the correct interpretation is to choose $3$ stops out of $7$ *first*, and then $2$ out of $6$, $2$ out of $4$, and $2$ out of $2$ passengers, giving
$$
\frac{\displaystyle{7\choose 3}{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2}}{7^6}
$$
as the correct answer.

So clearly,  I must have overcounted some things. Comparing the two answers we see that
$$
{7\choose 1}{6\choose 1}{6\choose 1} = 3!{7\choose 3}
$$
which leads me to believe I counted all $3$-sub*tuples* (as opposed to sub*sets*) of $7$ elements, but doesn't order *matter* for these cases?

Assume we have two tuples, $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(3, 2, 1)$. In ${7\choose 3}$, these would correspond to the same subset ${1, 2, 3}$. In the first tuple, this means the first two choices of passengers get off at stop 1, then the second two at stop 2, then the third two at stop 3. In the second, the frist two get off at stop 3, then the second two at stop 2, then the third two at stop 1.

Is the reason this is double-counting because since the second tuple is a permutation of the first tuple, we can just choose the first two passengers in the second tuple to be the last two passengers in the first tuple, and the last two passengers in the second tuple to be the first two passengers in the first tuple?

Comment: You appear to be neglecting the symmetry in the second case.  Saying that $A,B$ get off on $1$ and $C,D$ get off on $2$ is the same as saying that $C,D$ get off on $2$ and $A,B$ get off on $1$.  Note that there is no analogous symmetry in the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your calculation, you count each set of outcomes six times, once for each order in which you can select the three stations at which the passengers depart the train.

Suppose passengers $A$ and $B$ depart the train at the first station, $C$ and $D$ depart the train at the second station, and $E$ and $F$ depart the train at the third station.  You count this in six ways:

station 1: $A, B$; station 2: $C, D$; station 3: $E, F$

station 1: $A, B$; station 3: $E, F$; station 2: $C, D$

station 2: $C, D$; station 1: $A, B$; station 3: $E, F$

station 2: $C, D$; station 3: $E, F$; station 1: $A, B$

station 3: $E, F$; station 1: $A, B$; station 2: $C, D$

station 3: $E, F$; station 2: $C, D$; station 1: $A, B$

where the choices are listed in the order you selected the three stations.